# Why does Intellij not release memory after closing a project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I had three projects open. One of them - Spark - was very large. Upon closing spark there was NO difference in memory usage - as reported by os/x activity monitor. Note: all projects are opened within the same Intellij instance.

[image]

It is in fact using just over 4GB.  And I only *now* have two projects open. Those two projects only take up 1.5GB if I shut down Intellij and start it up again.

So .. what to do to "encourage" Intellij to release the memory it is using?  It is running very very slowly (can not keep up with my typing for example)

**Update** I just closed the larger of the two remaining projects. **STILL** no reduction in memory usage. The remaining project is a **single python file**. So Intellij should be using under 512Meg at this point!

Comment: Do you open each project in a separate window? Could you please clarify the steps you take while opening projects?

Comment: I think you should file a bug report instead.

Comment: Assuming it's actually free heap and not a memory leak in IntelliJ, you could try playing with [`-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20Total%20Heap|outline).

Comment: @rbento  Updated the OP: all are in the same Intellij instance.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Nice info - please add answer for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on @PeterGromov's answer it seems that is were *difficult* to obtain the memory back. In addition @KevinKrumwiede mentioned the `XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` which appears to be an avenue.

Here are a couple of those ideas taken bit farther from [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os)

> The HotSpot JVM does release memory back to the OS, but does so
>   reluctantly.
>
> You can make it more aggressive by setting -XX:GCTimeRatio=19
>   -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 which will allow it to spend more CPU time on collecting and constrain the amount of
>   allocated-but-unused heap memory after a GC cycle.
>
> Additionally with Java 9 -XX:-ShrinkHeapInSteps option can be be used
>   to apply the shrinking caused by the previous two options more
>   aggressively. Relevant OpenJDK bug.
>
> Do note that shrinking ability and behavior depends on the chosen
>   garbage collector. For example G1 only gained the ability to yield
>   back unused chunks in the middle of the heap with jdk8u20.
>
> So if heap shrinking is needed it should be tested for a particular
>   JVM version and GC configuration.

and from [How to free memory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567979/how-to-free-memory-in-java)

> To extend upon the answer and comment by Yiannis Xanthopoulos and Hot
>   Licks (sorry, I cannot comment yet!), you can set VM options like this
>   example:
>
> -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 In my jdk 7 this will then release unused VM memory if more than 30% of the heap
>   becomes free after GC when the VM is idle. You will probably need to
>   tune these parameters.
>
> While I didn't see it emphasized in the link below, note that some
>   garbage collectors may not obey these parameters and by default java
>   may pick one of these for you, should you happen to have more than one
>   core (hence the UseG1GC argument above).

I am going to add the  `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` to IJ and report back if it were to help.

Our application presently only runs on Java7 so the first approach above is not *yet* viable - but there is hope since our app is moving to jdk8 soon.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/status-bar.html

I used this:

Shows the current heap level and memory usage. Visibility of this section in the Status bar is defined by the Show memory indicator check box in the Appearance page of the Settings/Preferences dialog. It is not shown by default.
**Click the memory indicator to run the garbage collector.**

Comment: The link may stop working, and other users could not find useful your answer. Please try integrate some explanation in your answer

Comment: I don't know man. In the memory indicator it shows ONLY 624 MB used our of 1923 MB, while windows tells me PyCharm is actually using 1.5 GB of memory. I then clicked on the memory indicator and it released some 400MB memory but WIndows still show the same memory usage. I suspect it actually just released the memory to an "allocated pool", not to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Java virtual machine supports only growing of its heap. So even if after closing all projects the IDE doesn't need all of it, it's still allocated and counted as used in the OS.

Comment: This was a helpful comment but not completely correct it seems (see my answer below)